# How can I indicate in a Swift that key of for loop is NSString?

Tags: ios, core-data, for-loop, swift

Here I have a for loop. I know that I store NSStrings in it. How can I indicate the type  of `attributeName`? I do not want to write everywhere inside the loop, that `(relationshipName as NSString)`.

```
for attributeName in managedObject.entity.attributesByName.keys {
}
```

## UPDATE

If I add `[String]` and of the for loop declaration, I get the following error:

[image]
[image]

## UPDATE

as String has also problem

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to cast the dictionary returned by `attributesByName` to the real key/value type:

```
let attributes = managedObject.entity.attributesByName as [String: NSAttributeDescription]
for attributeName in attributes.keys  {
    // attributeName has the type String
    // ...
}
```

or

```
let attributes = managedObject.entity.attributesByName as [NSString: NSAttributeDescription]
for attributeName in attributes.keys  {
    // attributeName has the type NSString
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the `NSArray` returned by an ObjC API (which turns into `[AnyObject]!` by default) to a typed array:

```
for attributeName in managedObject.entity.attributesByName.keys as [String] {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for attributeName: String in managedObject.entity.attributesByName.keys {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly give the `attributeName` a type like `attributeName:NSString`

```
for  attributeName:NSString   in managedObject.entity.attributesByName.keys {

    attributeName.length  //here attributeName will work as NSString
}
```

and note `import Foundation` for implicity casting between `String` and `NSString` any