# How to use reflection with Core Data and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, reflection

I'm trying to use reflection in Swift with Core Data entities, but when I execute the following code, my reflected var has only a reference for a super class, it didn't have a reference for any of it's attributes.

```
func printProperties() {
    let mirror = reflect(self)
    for var i = 0; i < mirror.count; i++ {
        let (propertyName, childMirror) = mirror[i]
        println("property name: \(propertyName)")
        println("property value: \(childMirror.value)")
    }
}
```

Does anyone have some idea why this happens?

---

Update: As suggested by Anderson in his answer I tried another approach and ended up with this code:

```
func loadFromJson(json: JSON) {
    for attributeKey in self.entity.attributesByName.keys {
        let attributeDescription = self.entity.propertiesByName[attributeKey]!
            as! NSAttributeDescription
        let attributeClassName = attributeDescription.attributeValueClassName
        let jsonValue = json[(attributeKey as! String)]
        var attributeValue: AnyObject? = attributeDescription.defaultValue
        if jsonValue.type != .Null && attributeClassName != nil {
            if attributeClassName == "NSNumber" {
                attributeValue = jsonValue.number!
            } else if attributeClassName == "NSString" {
                attributeValue = jsonValue.string!
            }
        }
        setValue(attributeValue, forKey: (attributeKey as! String))
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason *could* be that the property accessors are generated dynamically at runtime. You could inspect the entity description instead , see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968282/how-can-i-indicate-in-a-swift-that-key-of-for-loop-is-nsstring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that this code can help you.
I wrote this extension to make a dictionary from a NSmanagedObject and it accesses  all attributes and values of the object.

```
extension NSManagedObject {

    func toDict() -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject>! {

        let attributes = self.entity.attributesByName.keys
        let relationships = self.entity.relationshipsByName.keys
        var dict: [String: AnyObject] = [String: AnyObject]()
        var dateFormater = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

        for attribute in attributes {
            if self.entity.propertiesByName[attribute]!.attributeValueClassName != nil && self.entity.propertiesByName[attribute]!.attributeValueClassName == "NSDate" {
                let value: AnyObject? = self.valueForKey(attribute as! String)
                if value != nil {
                    dict[attribute as! String] = dateFormater.stringFromDate(value as! NSDate)
                } else {
                    dict[attribute as! String] = ""
                }

            } else {
                let value: AnyObject? = self.valueForKey(attribute as! String)
                dict[attribute as! String] = value
            }
        }

        for attribute in relationships {
            let relationship: NSManagedObject = self.valueForKey(attribute as! String) as! NSManagedObject
            let value = relationship.valueForKey("key") as! String
            dict[attribute as! String] = value
        }

        return dict
    }
}
```

I hope to have helped you.

Comment: That's not exactly the answer for my question, but indeed helped a lot. I was trying to do an automatic object mapper from json to my Core Data entities, and I could accomplish that with your approach. Thanks! :)